# Query not returning records with a boolean column set to FALSE?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

This one is driving me mad - I must be missing something very simple here but have been Googling for 2 hours and have got nowhere. I'm building a Rails app with Postgresql 9.5.1 that handles appointments for barbers. One of the columns is available - if the appointment is available to book or not - it's a boolean. I need to get the next 5 records for a given appointment ID.

```
select *
from appointments
where id > 13
and barber_id = 1
limit 5
```

This returns 5 records, but the available field is all true, even though records 14-18 exist with attributes of available = FALSE.

[image: Screenshot from Postico of the table]

If I use the query

```
select * from appointments where id > 13 and barber_id = 1 and (available = false) limit 5
```

Then it returns only records with available = FALSE, but I want all records that match, whether TRUE or FALSE.

I have also tried

```
select * from appointments where id > 13 and barber_id = 1 and (available = false or available = true) limit 5
```

But this also only returns available = TRUE records.

Tearing my hair out here - what am I missing?! A default or something?

Comment: Just about `available = false`. There is another way to check boolean value: `length(available::text) < 5` ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your id's are not in sorted order, you might want to sort them and return

```
    select * from appointments where id > 13 and barber_id = 1 and
           (available = false or available = true) order by id asc limit 5
```

And your boolean thing can be completely removable if it is a not null column, since you are checking for both true and false :)

Comment: That was it, thank you! Database was all jumbled up and assumed it would just look for IDs in sequential order.